# Revocation Info in PDF Digitally Signature

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature

How can I get the revocation information for each of the signatures, in a digitally signed pdf document with several signatures, using the Itext library in java?

I appreciate the help.

Comment: What have you tried? What stopped you? And what iText version are you using?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers.

I am using itext 5.5.5. 
I have tried obtaining the DDS of the signed pdf to verify the CRLs and OCSPs in this way: 
`PdfDictionary dss = reader.getCatalog().getAsDict(PdfName.DSS);`
however the information I obtain is general for all the signatures and that is as far as I got because if I have a document with 3 firms and only 2 have an OCSP response I don't know which firms they belong to.

Comment: iText does not have the feature of returning matchings pairs of certificates and revocation information to the user. But it has a class for verifying the document signatures using the revocation information in the DSS, the `LtvVerifier`. Thus, you can find the required code pieces in that class.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. With the `LtvVerifier` class I was able to do what I was looking for.